# Erro: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"

Tags: php, mysql

Acabei de criar um domínio na locaweb e criei um site e um banco de dados.

Quando acesso o site, ele carrega parte da página, mas estou com o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/storage/9/04/78/gabrieldevito/public_html/gentelella-master/production/Classes/Persistencia/ContaCrud.php on line 44

A classe de conexão com o banco é:

```
class Connection {

    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $dbname = 'usodecontas';
    public $username = 'root';
    public $password = 'abc123';

    public function conectar() {
        try {

            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->dbname}", $this->username, $this->password);

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $conn;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}
```

Gente, o suporte da locaweb é terrível e eu não estou conseguindo achar algum tutorial que me ajude a fazer uma conexão remota no servidor pra que eu consiga aplicar alguns comandos que existe em outros tópicos. Alguém já passou por problemas semelhantes?

Obrigado.

Comment: Provavelmente muita gente já passou por problemas semelhantes. Foi só eu sair pra Amazon que os problemas acabaram (não é spam, não sou filiado à Amazon de forma alguma, mero cliente). O mais engraçado: TRES MESES depois que eu encerrei o servidor da LW, já tendo apagado tudo que podia antes da remoção, recebi um email alertando que o servidor tava fora do ar kkkkkk. E uns 8 meses depois, recebi por email  convite com link pra um evento deles, e... o link não funcionava :) ! provavelmente pq a minha conta não foi mais encontrada lá. Uma beleza a integração das coisas.

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da versão do PHP e as configurações do php.ini utilizar php dentro de chaves, não vai funcionar, tente concatenar para ver se é esse o erro

de:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->dbname}", $this->username, $this->password);
```

Para

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->username, $this->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive o mesmo problema que você para conectar ao meu banco, depois de algum tempo percebi que eram alguns ajustes que eu precisava fazer, segue o que foi feito e espero que te ajude:

1. Altere a senha do banco dentro da Locaweb (e altere no seu código também para que ele faça o vínculo necessário)
2. Código de conexão:

   ```
   $connection=mysql_connect ("usodecontas.mysql.dbaas.com.br", "root", "abc123");
   if (!$connection) {
     die('Sem Conexão : ' . mysql_error());
   }
   ```

Importante: mesmo você trabalhando de forma local (dentro do servidor), o host não pode ser localhost, tem que ser o nome do seu servidor, por exemplo: usodecontas.mysql.dbaas.com.br, dá uma olhada como é o seu dentro da locaweb, em banco de dados.

Segue o arquivo que usei de referência:

https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_conectar_a_um_banco_MySQL_atrav%C3%A9s_de_script_PHP